# Store customers payment information after checkout

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-api

I'm trying to created an upsell function after the user goes through the Shopify checkout.

I know how to redirect after checkout, but is there a way to save the customers payment information in order to show them an upsell product for them to click on the button with their stored payment information and buy the product without having to repeat the checkout process

Comment: @eyllanesc did you happen to find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the new Shopify Upsell API? Or is this a question based on already mastering the use of that API? Hard to tell.

Comment: Hi @David Lazar where can I find the shopify upsell api? cant seem to find the documentation on shopify tutorial for it.

Comment: https://shopify.dev/tutorials/sell-through-the-checkout-api   everything upsell is possible with that API. It is how all the upsell Apps work their magic.